# Splitting a string not working

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm trying to split a string but there is something wrong. If anyone could please advise.

```
echo -e "\e[41m## i = $i ##\e[0m"   
str1=$i | cut -d'/' -f1
echo -e "\e[41m## str1 = $str1 ##\e[0m"
```

and this is the output:

```
## i = 1000/1.0, ##
## str1 =  ##
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this:

```
str1=$(echo $i | cut -f1 -d'/')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash, there's no need to invoke an external command such as `cut` for this: you can use the shell's built-in parameter expansion functions.

For example to remove the longest trailing string starting with `/` from variable `str='1000/1.0'` and assign the result to variable `str1`

```
str1="${str%%/*}"
```

So

```
$ str='1000/1.0'
$ str1="${str%/*}"
$ echo "$str1"
1000
```

See the excellent [BashFAQ/073](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)